# When is `__dict__` re-initialized?

Tags: python, dictionary

I subclass `dict` so that the attributes are identical to the keys:

```
class DictWithAttr(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__ = self
        super(DictWithAttr, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(id(self), id(self.__dict__))

    def copy(self):
        return DictWithAttr(self.__dict__)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr({k:v for k, v in self.items() if k != '__dict__'})
```

and it works as expected:

```
d = DictWithAttr(x=1, y=2)    # 139917201238328 139917201238328
d.y = 3
d.z = 4
d['w'] = 5
print(d)                      # {'x': 1, 'y': 3, 'z': 4, 'w': 5}
print(d.__dict__)             # {'x': 1, 'y': 3, 'z': 4, 'w': 5}
print(d.z, d.w)               # 4 5
```

But if I re-write `__setattr__` as

```
    ...
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value
    ...
```

then `__dict__` will be re-created in initialization and the attributes will turn inaccessible:

```
d = DictWithAttr(x=1, y=2)    # 140107290540344 140107290536264
d.y = 3
d.z = 4
d['w'] = 5
print(d)                      # {'x': 1, 'y': 3, 'z': 4, 'w': 5}
print(d.__dict__)             # {}
print(d.z, d.w)               # AttributeError: 'DictWithAttr' object has no attribute 'z'
```

Adding a paired `__getattr__` as below will get around the `AttributeError`

```
    ...
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self[key]
    ...
```

but still `__dict__` is cleared:

```
d = DictWithAttr(x=1, y=2)    # 139776897374520 139776897370944
d.y = 3
d.z = 4
d['w'] = 5
print(d)                      # {'x': 1, 'y': 3, 'z': 4, 'w': 5}
print(d.__dict__)             # {}
print(d.z, d.w)               # 4 5
```

Thanks for any explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reinitialization. Your problem is that `self.__dict__ = self` hits your `__setattr__` override. It's not actually changing the dict used for attribute lookups. It's setting an entry for the `'__dict__'` key on `self` and leaving the attribute dict untouched.

If you wanted to keep your (pointless) `__setattr__` override, you could bypass it in `__init__`:

```
object.__setattr__(self, '__dict__', self)
```

but it'd be easier to just take out your `__setattr__` override. While you're at it, take out that `__repr__`, too - once you fix your code, the only reason there would be a `'__dict__'` key is if a user sets it themselves, and if they do that, you should show it.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you should overwrite `__getattr__`, `__setattr__` and `__delattr__`.

```
class DictWithAttr(dict):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]

    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        del self[name]

    def __dir__(self):
        return dir({}) + list(self.keys())
```

The reason of your problem has been pointed out by user2357112.

Comment: If you want to go with stuff like `__setattr__ = dict.__setitem__`, you can do that with `__getattr__` and `__delattr__` too. `__getattr__ = dict.__getitem__` and `__delattr__ = dict.__delitem__`.

Comment: Also, if you're going with this kind of approach instead of the original `self.__dict__` replacement, then using `__slots__ = ()` could be handy. It eliminates `self.__dict__` entirely, saving a bunch of memory and reducing opportunities to accidentally put things in the wrong dict.

Comment: @user2357112 For your first point, yes. The reason why I leave them here because we can add some other condition such as raising exceptions if the key doesn't exist. For your second point, well, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Simple, addresses nested dicts and correct AttributeError, although being very small:

```
class DotDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, d: dict = {}):
        super().__init__()
        for key, value in d.items():
            self[key] = DotDict(value) if type(value) is dict else value
    
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return self[key]
        raise AttributeError(key) #Set proper exception, not KeyError

    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
```